# Vue3 + Pinia - how to remove element from array in store

Tags: vuejs3, pinia

I have a vue3 application with a pinia store. There sits an array

```
[{
   "name":"foo",
   "age":"2"
 },
 {
   "name":"bar",
   "age":"5"
}]
```

I loop over it in my component:

```html
<div v-for="el in myarray">
 <btn @click=store.remove(el)
</div>
```

successfully.

```
const store = useStore()  
myarray = storeToRefs(useStore())
```

are there.

The click calls this method in the store:

```js
remove(name, x) {
  this.myarray[name] = this.myarray[name].filter((v) => {
    return v !== x;
  });
```

I used to work with an array in my vue component but now it deletes random entries.
I tried to loop the array with
`v-for="{el, index} from myarray"` as recommended (for non-pinia situations) but this spits errors.

So in general: What is the correct way to

1. access arrays from a pinia store
2. delete an entry from this array
   ?

Comment: isn't `this.myarray[facet]` getting one object from the array, so then how is `.filter` (an array function) supposed to work? also, what are example values here that you're working with?  what is `facet`? what is the contents of the array before and after `remove_filter_p`?  I would just want to walk through what's happening step by step and confirm the behavior of the function. nothing just happens "randomly".

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to remove stuff. I try to generalise my case.

Comment: `(el, index) of myarray` should work. Btw, try to add `:key="element unique key"` to your `v-for` loop

Answer (score 0):

It was jaust a syntax error. It should be `v-for=(el, index) in myarray`. I used {} which is wrong here.